# Time Interval Checker

Tags: formula

Need your help with regards the time stamp how can I create a formula that checks the date if it is less than 8 months

Verification <=  DAY(TODAY()) -6

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Please write a clear detailed explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little buried in documentation, but the behavior you're asking about (what does `today() - <integer>` mean?) is documented.

From https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5 (emphasis mine)

> **You can use operations like addition and subtraction on Date and Date/Time values to calculate a future date or elapsed time between two dates**. If you subtract one date from another, for example, the resulting value will be the difference between the two initial values in days (Number data type). The same operation between two Date/Time values returns a decimal value indicating the difference in number of days, hours, and minutes.
>
> For example, if the difference between two Date/Time values is 5.52, that means the two values are separated by five days, 12 hours (0.5 of a day), and 28 minutes (0.02 of a day). **You can also add numeric values to Dates and Date/Times. For example, the operation TODAY() + 3 returns three days after today’s date**. For more information and examples of working with dates, see the list of Sample Date Formulas.

So there it is, `Today() +/- <integer>` will either add or subtract that number of days. 8 months is roughly 240 days. Substitute as required.

Yes, 8 months will not always be exactly 240 days (especially if February is involved), but formulas in Salesforce aren't really well-suited for anything but the most simple of date/time manipulation. If you want more precision, you should consider Apex (and be prepared to spend a lot of time working on it).